# Entity Framework convention for 1to1 relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've looked through various sources and in most of them I see the convention of Entity Framework for 1to1 relationship as eg.

```
public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
```

However I found also:

```
public virtual Product Products {get;set;}
```

Would there be some specific reason to use the latter convention? I know in one to many it goes `Products` as below, but I'm particularily interested about 1to1 convention.

```
public virtual ICollection<Product>Products{get;set;}
```

Comment: Why would anyone name a `1:1` relationship `Products` (plural)? Maybe you're referring to the `PluralizingTableNameConvention` (which means that the database *table name* will be pluralized)? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: It's still a one-to-one relationship, so the name of the prop doesn't matter. For all we know it's a typo. If you're asking if there's any reason to use a pluralized spelling of a property that's not a Collection, the answer is no (unless you're trying to confuse everybody).

Comment: Maybe a typo? This is not a convention afaik, and not exclusively related to EF, but OOP in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a `Typo` in those examples you saw.

Plural names typically indicate a collection, even if there is only 1 item in the collection.

Keep it non-S.